# Form not passing through hidden field value correctly in Facebook, but ok elsewhere

Tags: facebook, forms, symfony-forms

I have a script that first checks if the form page is referred from a GET parameter

```
$page['is_referred'] = isset($_GET['rfr']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Then that set value is used as the value of a hidden field in a Symfony2 form

```
$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
    //....
    ->add('referred', 'hidden', array(
        'data' => $page['is_referred'],
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

then

```
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {

    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        //...
        $referred  = $form->get('referred')->getData();

        $msg_referer   = "Thanks from Referrer";
        $msg_noreferer = "Thanks";

        if( 1 == $referred ){
            $page['thanks'] = $msg_referer;
        }else{
            $page['thanks'] = $msg_noreferer;
        }
        //..
    }
}
```

The hidden field is read okay on the main site when `?rfr` is in the url, but when iframed in Facebook and `?rfr` is present, the $msg_noreferer message is displayed instead. Any ideas as to why this happens?

EDIT: I should also mention that the field value is correctly set in Facebook when I check the source, but it just doesn't seem to post the data through correctly

Comment: Much intensive searching suggests that Facebook doesn't allow hidden form fields to be posted. Unable to verify it, however.

Comment: That’s definitively wrong. What happens inside the iframe is not Facebook’s concern.

Answer (score 0):

> I should also mention that the field value is correctly set in Facebook when I check the source, but it just doesn't seem to post the data through correctly

I’d say, the value is posted alright, but the form validation does not accept it, because the hidden field does *not* get added to the form on validation.

Have you *checked* this, if the code adding the hidden field to the form is actually being executed when handling the POST request received from the browser …?